# Swiftkey backup & sync not working

Tags: 9.0-pie, swiftkey

I am using Swiftkey 7.4.0.18 on Android 9 (before that, on Android 7). I got a new phone and installed Swiftkey on it, logged in and enabled backup & sync. My personal dictionary had been correctly backed up before, I can see that in the "View and manage your data" section. The dictionary contains several hundred or thousand words (I speak a special German dialect, that's why). However, these learned words do not show up on my new phone, even though sync appears to "work" as there is no error message. I have contacted Swiftkey support a while ago but haven't heard anything.

Anybody here who can tell me how I can debug / solve this?

Comment: I am also a SwiftKey user and this feature has never worked for me. The problem is same as yours.

Comment: This is so dumb. Is there no way to get support?

Comment: I would say that SwiftKey Support is not 'exceptional'.

Comment: This is a problem voiced by many users but ignored - see https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115002929809/comments/360008235792.